# redeployment must fail if previous deployment of the same release succeeded-

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have to prevent an already succeded release from being deployed on production environment again. So I need fo find the status of the previous deployment on production when the same release is deployed again, and check if it succeeded. If so, no deployment should be possible.

However. As soon as I deploy the release again the production status changes from "succeeded" to "in progress" which ofcourse causes redeployment to succeed.

IS anyone familiar with this problem and is there a way to start the deployment and check the status of the previous deployment to production os that same release?

Comment: Hi there, is there any updates for this issue? Please check whether my answer below can help you and feel free to comment~

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REST API [Deployments - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/deployments/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#get-all-deployments-in-the-project) to get a list of releases. Note the [URI Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/deployments/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#uri-parameters) if you want to specify the range of releases you get.

Then you can send this REST API in a PowerShell task. **Please notice that you are not going to get the current release, you are going to get the last release.**

Here is an example and my log:

```
$token = "{pat}"
$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))
$url="https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/Release/deployments?definitionId={id}&queryOrder=descending&api-version=6.0"
$head = @{ Authorization =" Basic $token" }
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method GET -Headers $head -ContentType application/json-patch+json
echo $result.value[1].deploymentStatus
```

[image]

You can get the status of last release by `$result.value[1].deploymentStatus` and you will always get `inProgress` by `$result.value[0].deploymentStatus`. In this example I set that `queryOrder` to `descending`. You can also ignore this parameter because the REST API defaults to ordering in descending order.